# After uploading an image to google cloud, how can I get a link to that image?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

After uploading an image, I get back metadata that has a mediaDownloadLink that will download the file when accessed. Is there a way to get a link that will display the image in the browser without downloading it?

Answer (score 1):

In general, any object you set to be publicly accessible (which presumably you wanted to do to use it to host images on a website), you can then access with `https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/<object>`. You can see this link also if you go to the [cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser) and make an object publicly viewable and look for the `Public link` you can click.

If you have problems with the link downloading instead of displaying by itself in a browser, you may need to make sure the `content-type` header is set correctly; for example if using ByteArrayContent to upload data using the Java API, you'll want to set a string like "image/jpeg" in its [constructor for "type"](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/http/ByteArrayContent#ByteArrayContent(java.lang.String,%20byte[])).